# setRenderer() method in Extjs4

Tags: extjs, extjs4

`Extjs 3.3.1` have the method `setRenderer()` as

```
/**
  * Sets the rendering (formatting) function for a column. 
  */
setRenderer( Number col, Function fn ) : void
```

Now I don't get any method in `ExtJS 4` of `setRenderer`. So How can I format grid column at runtime in `ExtJS 4`.

Comment: I have   doubt, If you have chat permission [look this](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7451/extjs-3-x-4-x-java-script-framework)

Answer (score 0):

When you're creating your grid you can define the renderer on each column...

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Grid Sample',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('yourStore'),
    columns: [
        {header: 'Product Description',  dataIndex: 'description'},
        {header: 'Cost', dataIndex: 'cost', renderer: nameOfRenderFunction },
    ],
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

And then you can define your function in a global scope...

```
function nameOfRenderFunction(v) {
    //do something to v
    return v;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer But I would like to change grid columns which once rendered & without destroy the grid.
Means I have two grids, I wana change second grid columns on itemClick or cellClick of first Grid Columns. & I got a method for reconfigure to the GridPanel in Extjs.

reconfigure( Ext.data.Store store, Array columns ) : void

Reconfigure the table with a new store/column. Either the store or the column can be omitted if you don't wish to change them.
Parameters

    store : Ext.data.Store

    The new store.
    columns : Array

    An array of column configs

Returns

    void

Comment: I don't see a `reconfigure` method in `Ext.grid.Panel`? There is one in `Ext.panel.Table` though.

Comment: We can also use it for GridPanel.
for i.e- gridPanel.reconfigure(store,columns);

Answer (score 0):

What I did was set the renderer after the fact. After my application launched, I got the instantiated component and added a renderer in my controller's onLaunch() function like this:

```
    // An example renderer
    var myComponentsRenderer = function( value ){
        return value++;
    };

    // Get the instantiated component
    var myComponent = Ext.ComponentQuery.query( "#myComponent" )[0];

    // Attach the renderer
    Ext.override( myComponent, {
        renderer : myComponentsRenderer,
    });
```

The reason I like this method is because I am able to put the renderer functions in my controller and keep logic out of my view. It helps me organize my code better.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like the the way to do it is mentioned in passing in [this post on the sencha forum](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?131592-Setting-up-a-column-renderer-via-the-grid-s-reconfigure%28%29-function).

You can use a [grid's reconfigure method](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-method-reconfigure) to swap in a different list of columns (along with renderers) however this does have the major downside that you'll have to totally respecify the columns in their entirety.

Did you find a better way?  I really dont like the fact it forces you to put renderers in a place where they can't be tested and can't access state in a none static way.

However it seems the cure is worse than the disease in this case as you'd end up taking what is very definitely view code out of the view.

Sometimes it feels like they didn't really think about the design of these things very much :(